# Implementing non-rational transfer function in Simulink

Tags: matlab, function, simulink, transfer

I have to implement the following transfer function in `simulink`:

```
(25s² + 7.5s + 1)(1 + 6s)/((1 + 2s)³ - (1 + 6s)*exp(-3s))
```

I can't find a way to implement this with the `'Transfer Fcn'` block, because it only seems to accept a rational numerator and denominator.

Is there any way to achieve this? Purpose is to build an internal model controller.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know is you have to do an rational approximation for your transfer function before implementing in Simulink. It is actually the PADE approximation for the time-delay part: you approximate the exp(-Ts) by a m-th order Taylor polynominal.

I personally have never been in detailed with this, but i know Matlab also has [Padé approximation of model with time delays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pade.html).

UPDATE:

I try to make an example of full-implementation, hope it helps. In the example i used the `third-order pade approximation` as Matlab's example. But you have to choose the order yourself to best adapt your problem.

```
>> s = tf('s');
>> sys = (1+6*s)*exp(-3*s);
>> mysys = (25*s^2 + 7.5*s + 1)*(1 + 6*s)/(1 + 2*s)^3 - pade(sys, 3)

mysys =

   48 s^7 + 38 s^6 + 718 s^5 + 1434 s^4 + 1106 s^3 + 267.8 s^2 + 20 s
  --------------------------------------------------------------------
  8 s^6 + 44 s^5 + 107.3 s^4 + 140.6 s^3 + 97.33 s^2 + 33.33 s + 4.444

Continuous-time transfer function.
```

Now, since the transfer function is in improper form (more zeros than poles), so you must break it down into combination of proper forms:

```
>> [num,den] = tfdata(mysys, 'v');
>> [r,p,~]=residue(num,den)

r =

   1.0e+02 *

   0.1298 + 0.8244i
   0.1298 - 0.8244i
   1.5805 + 0.0000i
  -0.1937 + 0.0000i
   0.0700 + 0.0000i
  -0.0088 + 0.0000i


p =

  -1.2259 + 1.1696i
  -1.2259 - 1.1696i
  -1.5481 + 0.0000i
  -0.5000 + 0.0000i
  -0.5000 + 0.0000i
  -0.5000 + 0.0000i
```

And finally, use a for-loop to build up your child-transfer-functions from arrays `r` and `p` (arrays of child-tf's `num` and `den`). I am not sure if you can use `arrayfun` with output type `transfer function` or not.

```
for i = 1:length(r)
    mysystems(i) = tf(r(i), [1, -p(i)]);
end
```